# make error during building webkitgtk

Tags: linux, cmake, makefile

I use UBuntu 14.04 LTS. I need to build webkitgtk 2.8.3 Here is an example instruction which I have used: [linuxfromscratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/webkitgtk.html) When I run `sudo make -j8` I get following log:

```
Scanning dependencies of target JavaScriptCore-4-gir
Scanning dependencies of target fake-generated-webkitdom-headers
[  0%] Scanning dependencies of target WebKit2-fake-api-headers
Scanning dependencies of target translations_1
[  0%] Generating ../../JavaScriptCore-4.0.typelib
[  0%] /bin/sh: 1: ../../JavaScriptCore-4.0.gir: Permission denied
Scanning dependencies of target bmalloc
[  0%] [  0%] make[2]: *** [JavaScriptCore-4.0.typelib] Error 126
Generating ../../DerivedSources/webkitdom/WebKitDOMCustom.h
make[1]: *** [Source/JavaScriptCore/CMakeFiles/JavaScriptCore-     4-gir.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....Generating     ../../DerivedSources/webkitdom/WebKitDOMDeprecated.h
```

What might be wrong ?

**Edit1** Verbose log:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/MyProjects/midori_dependencies/src/webkitgtk-2.8.3/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/user/MyProjects/midori_dependencies/src/webkitgtk-2.8.3/build/CMakeFiles 
[  0%] [  0%] make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/MyProjects/midori_dependencies/src/webkitgtk-2.8.3/build'
cd /home/user/MyProjects/midori_dependencies/src/webkitgtk-2.8.3/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/user/MyProjects/midori_dependencies/src/webkitgtk-2.8.3 /home/user/MyProjects/midori_dependencies/src/webkitgtk-2.8.3/Source/WebKit2 /home/user/MyProjects/midori_dependencies/src/webkitgtk-2.8.3/build /home/user/MyProjects/midori_dependencies/src/webkitgtk-2.8.3/build/Source/WebKit2 /home/user/MyProjects/midori_dependencies/src/webkitgtk-2.8.3/build/Source/WebKit2/CMakeFiles/WebKit2-forwarding-headers.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/MyProjects/midori_dependencies/src/webkitgtk-2.8.3/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/user/MyProjects/midori_dependencies/src/webkitgtk-2.8.3/build/CMakeFiles 
[  0%] Generating ../../JavaScriptCore-4.0.typelib
cd /home/user/MyProjects/midori_dependencies/src/webkitgtk-2.8.3/build/Source/JavaScriptCore && ../../JavaScriptCore-4.0.gir -o /home/user/MyProjects/midori_dependencies/src/webkitgtk-2.8.3/build/JavaScriptCore-4.0.typelib
/bin/sh: 1: ../../JavaScriptCore-4.0.gir: Permission denied
Generating ../../DerivedSources/ForwardingHeaders/webkit2gtk/webkit2
make[2]: *** [JavaScriptCore-4.0.typelib] Error 126
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/MyProjects/midori_dependencies/src/webkitgtk-2.8.3/build'
make[1]: *** [Source/JavaScriptCore/CMakeFiles/JavaScriptCore-4-gir.dir/all] Error 2
/usr/bin/*** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Comment: it seems `JavaScriptCore-4.0.gir` doesn't have the right permissions

Comment: I run make as root, JavaScriptCore-4.0.gir is generated during make

Comment: you should never compile code as root; beside, does `JavaScriptCore-4.0.gir` exist in `build` directory? can you run `g-ir-compiler JavaScriptCore-4.0.gir -o JavaScriptCore-4.0.typelib`?

Comment: Also try to use VERBOSE=yes so we can see what actual command was run.

Comment: JavaScriptCore-4.0.gir exists in the build directory and is generated during make. I can run -ir-compiler JavaScriptCore-4.0.gir -o JavaScriptCore-4.0.typelib

Comment: Please see Edit1 - Verbose log

Comment: I have the same problem. I think webkitgtk chokes on itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you see, in Edit1, you (make) try to run `JavaScriptCore-4.0.gir` instead of compile it with `g-ir-compiler`; I tried on my pc and my command is:

```
cd /home/davide/src/webkitgtk-2.8.3/build/Source/JavaScriptCore && \
    /usr/bin/g-ir-compiler /home/davide/src/webkitgtk-2.8.3/build/JavaScriptCore-4.0.gir \
    -o /home/davide/src/webkitgtk-2.8.3/build/JavaScriptCore-4.0.typelib
```

as a workaround, you cand edit:

`build/Source/JavaScriptCore/CMakeFiles/JavascriptCore-4-gir.dir/build`

here's the lines on my file (the last line is what you need to change):

```
JavaScriptCore-4.0.typelib: JavaScriptCore-4.0.gir
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_report /home/davide/src/webkitgtk-2.8.3/build/CMakeFiles $(CMAKE_PROGRESS_1)
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --blue --bold "Generating ../../JavaScriptCore-4.0.typelib"
    cd /home/davide/src/webkitgtk-2.8.3/build/Source/JavaScriptCore && /usr/bin/g-ir-compiler /home/davide/src/webkitgtk-2.8.3/build/JavaScriptCore-4.0.gir -o /home/davide/src/webkitgtk-2.8.3/build/JavaScriptCore-4.0.typelib
```

just add `/usr/bin/g-ir-compiler` or whatever it is located (`which g-ir-compiler`)

Comment: What is your cmake version ? I have 2.8.12.2

Comment: versdion 3.2.2; don't you have those line?

Comment: My CMake generates build.make file without /usr/bin/g-ir-compiler. I added it as you described and it works. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

webkitgtk-2.26.2/Source/cmake/OptionsGTK.cmake webkitgtk-2.26.2/Source/cmake/OptionsGTK.cmake
add bellow line

list(APPEND JavaScriptCore_LIBRARIES -latomic)

Comment: can you please provide some comment, why your solution would work?